# Quiero saber el costo total de la funcion

Tags: python

soy nuevo en Python y estaba haciendo un ejercicio donde quisiera saber como obtener el costo total , a partir de la suma de todas las funciones que salen (def costo hotel, def costo de vuelo, def costo rentar auto)...revise otra forma que  hay y es más efectiva y que también me resulta. Pero quisiera hacerlo de esta forma, como la escribí aquí. Si alguien me ayuda, se lo agradezco :

````
print("Bienvenido a la agencia de viaje")
def costo_hotel():
    noches = int(input("Cuantas noches deseas quedarte? "))
    costo = noches * 140
    print("El costo de la estadia en el hotel sera de $", costo)

costo_hotel()

def costo_del_vuelo():
    lugar = str(input("Donde gustarias ir?, responde con NY, los angeles, boston o tampa "))
    ny=183
    la=475
    bos=222
    tam=220
    if lugar == "NY":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a NY es de $183")
    elif lugar == "los angeles":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Los Angeles es de $475")
    elif lugar == "boston":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Boston es de $222")
    elif lugar == "tampa":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Tampa es de $220")
    else:
        print("Lo sentimos, vuelve a intentar")

costo_del_vuelo()

def costo_rentar_auto():
    dias = int(input("Cuantos dias rentarás el ferrari?, Recuerda que si rentas por menos de 7 dias tienes un descuento de $20, y si rentas por 7 días o más costará $50 por día "))
    cost = dias * 40
    if dias >= 7:
        print("El costo de la renta por", dias, " dias será de $", cost-50)
    elif dias < 7:
        print("El costo de la renta por", dias, " dias será de $", cost-20)

costo_rentar_auto()

def costo_total ():
    total = costo_hotel(noches) + costo_del_vuelo(lugar) +\
            costo_rentar_auto(dias)
    return total

costo_total= costo_hotel(int(noches)) +\
             costo_del_vuelo(lugar) +\
             costo_rentar_auto(int(dias))

costo_total()```
````

Comment: Eso no debe de funcionar e incluso debe de dar error. Primero añade el `return` correspondiente a cada función

Answer (score 1):

Como te decían en el comentario, tienes varios errores y tu código explota al ejecutarlo, así que trataré de explicarte algunos errores que tenías, todos partimos así alguna vez y creo que lo mejor es pedir ayuda y aprender de nuestros errores.

No soy dev en python pero intentaré que veas algunas cositas en las que estabas fallando

### Primero

tomé las variables que tenías dentro de las funciones **costo_hotel**, **costo_del_vuelo** y **costo_rentar_auto**. Es importante dejarlas globales ya que esos datos se utilizarán al final para poder hacer el calculo del total del viaje

nuestros valores quedarán guardados de manera global hasta que necesitemos utilizarlos.

### Segundo

Aquí te voy a dejar la parte de las funciones con los comentarios para que puedas ver que te faltaba, te faltaban los return de los valores para poder utilizarlos cuando calculas el total.

Tu código no funcionaba básicamente porque al no retornar valores en las funciones al calcular el total no estabas sumando nada, un ejemplo super absurdo es ir a comprar pan y pasarle el dinero al señor de la tienda y que no te entregue nada, algo parecido pasaba acá. Además que ejecutabas las funciones una por una y quien tenía que hacer esos llamados es la funcion de **costo_total**

```
def costo_hotel(noches):
    costo = noches * 140
    print("El costo de la estadia en el hotel sera de $", costo)
    return costo #aquí retornamos el costo para después calcular el total

def costo_del_vuelo(lugar):
    ny=183
    la=475
    bos=222
    tam=220
# Según el lugar al que vamos retornamos el costo
    if lugar == "NY":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a NY es de $ ", ny)
        return ny #Retorna 183
    elif lugar == "los angeles":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Los Angeles es de $", la)
        return la #Retorna 475
    elif lugar == "boston":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Boston es de $", bos)
        return bos #Retorna 222
    elif lugar == "tampa":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Tampa es de $", tam)
        return tam #Retorna 220
    else:
        print("Lo sentimos, vuelve a intentar")
        return 0
#Retorna 0 en caso de que no exista el lugar para que no se rompa el ejercicio, 
#debes ver otra forma de validar esto ya sea con alguna excepcion o algo

def costo_rentar_auto(dias):
    cost = dias * 40
    #Aquí guardé los valores de los decuentos en variables
    #Con esto se hace más fácil trabajar con ellos
    descuento_siete_o_mas_dias = 50
    descuento_siete_o_menos_dias = 20
    if dias >= 7:
        print("El costo de la renta por", dias, " dias será de $", cost-descuento_siete_o_mas_dias)
        #retornamos el costo - el descuento que almacenamos en la variable
        return cost - descuento_siete_o_mas_dias 
    elif dias < 7:
        print("El costo de la renta por", dias, " dias será de $", cost-descuento_siete_o_menos_dias)
        #retornamos el costo - el descuento que almacenamos en la variable
        return cost - descuento_siete_o_menos_dias
```

### Tercero

Como te mencioné anteriormente quien debe hacer las llamadas a las funciones **costo_hotel**, **costo_del_vuelo** y **costo_rentar_auto**. Es la funcion **costo_total**.

Aquí es cuando utilizamos los valores que dejamos guardados en las variables al comienzo de esta respuesta (eran una herramienta sorpresa, que nos ayudarían más adelante)

Con un ejemplo:

- Cuando costo total llama a la función costo_hotel() y le pasa un valor de 1 (costo_hotel(1)) va a entrar a la función, hará el calculo de 1 * 140 y nos retornara 140
- Cuando costo total llama a la función costo_del_vuelo() y le pasamos por ejemplo costo_del_vuelo("NY"), entraremos a la función verificaremos el destino y retornaremos 183
- Finalmente lo mismo con la ultima función del auto, le pasamos un valor de 6 días costo_rentar_auto(6), entra a la función, hará el calculo de dias * 40 y como son 6 días nos hará un descuento de 20, obteniendo así un valor de 220

Ahora si la función costo_total tiene todos los valores para poder entregarte tu respuesta que es 543

el valor del calculo solo se imprime ya que es información que va a leer el usuario por lo que no es necesario retornarlo.

Bueno creo que fue mucho texto, espero haberte ayudado y que te sirva para reforzar esos pequeños detalles, a todos nos pasa así que a no desanimarse y darle a la práctica !

```
def costo_total (noches, lugar, dias):
    total = costo_hotel(noches) + costo_del_vuelo(lugar) + costo_rentar_auto(dias)
    print("El costo total del viaje es de $", total)

costo_total(noches, lugar, dias)
```

### Código final para que puedas probar y revisar

```
print("Bienvenido a la agencia de viaje")

noches = int(input("Cuantas noches deseas quedarte? "))

dias = int(input("Cuantos dias rentarás el ferrari?, Recuerda que si rentas por menos de 7 dias tienes un descuento de $20, y si rentas por 7 días o más costará $50 por día "))

lugar = str(input("Donde gustarias ir?, responde con NY, los angeles, boston o tampa "))

def costo_hotel(noches):
    costo = noches * 140
    print("El costo de la estadia en el hotel sera de $", costo)
    return costo

def costo_del_vuelo(lugar):
    ny=183
    la=475
    bos=222
    tam=220
    if lugar == "NY":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a NY es de $ ", ny)
        return ny
    elif lugar == "los angeles":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Los Angeles es de $", la)
        return la
    elif lugar == "boston":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Boston es de $", bos)
        return bos
    elif lugar == "tampa":
        print("El costo de ida y vuelta a Tampa es de $", tam)
        return tam
    else:
        print("Lo sentimos, vuelve a intentar")
        return 0

def costo_rentar_auto(dias):
    cost = dias * 40
    descuento_siete_o_mas_dias = 50
    descuento_siete_o_menos_dias = 20
    if dias >= 7:
        print("El costo de la renta por", dias, " dias será de $", cost-descuento_siete_o_mas_dias)
        return cost - descuento_siete_o_mas_dias
    elif dias < 7:
        print("El costo de la renta por", dias, " dias será de $", cost-descuento_siete_o_menos_dias)
        return cost - descuento_siete_o_menos_dias

def costo_total (noches, lugar, dias):
    total = costo_hotel(noches) + costo_del_vuelo(lugar) + costo_rentar_auto(dias)
    print("El costo total del viaje es de $", total)

costo_total(noches, lugar, dias)
```

Comment: Te agradezco un montón Zoek tu ayuda, de mi parte como decía aprender de quienes saben es lo más importante de esta comunidad. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

```
PR_NOCHE_HOTEL = 140
PR_COCHE = 40
DTO_COCHE = 20
COCHE_7_DIAS = 50

VIAJAR_A = {
    'NY': 183,
    'LA': 475,
    'BOS': 222,
    'TAM': 220
}

def dame_numero(txt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(txt))
        except ValueError:
            print('No es un número válido')


def costo_hotel():
    noches = dame_numero("Cuantas noches deseas quedarte?: ")
    costo = noches * PR_NOCHE_HOTEL
    print(f'El costo de la estadia en el hotel sera de ${costo}')
    return costo


def costo_del_vuelo():
    while True:
        lugar = input(f"Donde gustarias ir?, responde con {list(VIAJAR_A.keys() )} ").upper()
        if lugar in VIAJAR_A: break
    print(f"El costo de ida y vuelta a {lugar} es de ${VIAJAR_A[lugar]}")
    return VIAJAR_A[lugar]


def costo_rentar_auto():
    dias = dame_numero("Cuantos dias rentarás el ferrari?,\n"
                     "Recuerda que si rentas por menos de 7 dias tienes un descuento de $20\n"
                     "y si rentas por 7 días o más costará $50 por día ")
    if dias >= 7:
        costo = COCHE_7_DIAS * dias
    else:
        costo = PR_COCHE * dias - DTO_COCHE

    print(f"El costo de la renta por {dias} dias será de ${costo}")
    return costo



def costo_total ():
    return costo_hotel() + costo_del_vuelo() + costo_rentar_auto()

while True:
    print("Bienvenido a la agencia de viaje")
    
    print(f'El costo total es de {costo_total()}')
    
    if input('Deseas otro viaje? [s/n]: ').lower() != 's': break
```

**Explicación:**

Para facilitar el código puedes guardar los viajes y sus precios en un diccionario.

Todos los precios y viajes los puedes poner como constantes.

```
PR_NOCHE_HOTEL = 140
PR_COCHE = 40
DTO_COCHE = 20
COCHE_7_DIAS = 50

VIAJAR_A = {
    'NY': 183,
    'LA': 475,
    'BOS': 222,
    'TAM': 220
}
```

Como se solicitan varias veces un número, una función que se asegure que se introducen datos correctos. Recibe el texto del `input` y pide el número hasta que sea un valor válido y lo devuelve.

```
def dame_numero(txt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(txt))
        except ValueError:
            print('No es un número válido')
```

La función del hotel llama a la función `def dame_numero(txt)` y devuelve el número de noches multiplicado por `PR_NOCHE_HOTEL` (constante con el precio/noche) y devuelve el importe.

```
def costo_hotel():
    noches = dame_numero("Cuantas noches deseas quedarte?: ")
    costo = noches * PR_NOCHE_HOTEL
    print(f'El costo de la estadia en el hotel sera de ${costo}')
    return costo
```

En la función de alquilar coche el `if/else` lo puedes evaluar de dos formas:

```
    if dias >= 7:
        costo = COCHE_7_DIAS * dias
    else:
        costo = PR_COCHE * dias - DTO_COCHE
```

y tambien así (operador ternario):

```
        costo = (COCHE_7_DIAS * dias) if dias >= 7 else (PR_COCHE * dias - DTO_COCHE)
```

La función `costo_total()` irá llamando a las otras funciones y recibiendo los valores de ellas.

```
def costo_total ():
    return costo_hotel() + costo_del_vuelo() + costo_rentar_auto()
```

La función principal (`main`) se ejecutará hasta que no reciba algo diferente a 's'

```
while True:
    print("Bienvenido a la agencia de viaje")
    print(f'El costo total es de {costo_total()}')
    if input('Deseas otro viaje? [s/n]: ').lower() != 's': break
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu explicación . Es importante, para mi el r comprendiendo, así que te lo agradezco